# Get Scanner Info

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net 2010 application and I would like to get the scanner info (modal name, port, etc.) attached with my PC. I use windows xp SP 3 in my machine and Cannon scanner is attached with my machine.

Kindly let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get that info from WMi windows management instrmentation